# Using NuGet from a PowerShell task in ADO

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, nuget, azure-pipelines

For a number of reasons, I need to be able to run NuGet within a PowerShell script from an Azure DevOps pipeline.

I've been able to put NuGet on the path and get the executable to run, but I can't get NuGet to restore the specified packages.

I thought it might be an authentication issue, but `nuget list` appears to list the package in question, while `nuget restore` errors out saying the package doesn't exist.

If I run the script locally, everything works just fine; the package restores as expected.

My ADO Pipeline looks like this:

```
  - task: NuGetToolInstaller@1
    inputs:
      versionSpec: 5.11.0
  - task: NugetAuthenticate@1
  - task: PowerShell@2
    displayName: 'Run script'
    inputs:
      targetType: 'filePath'
      filePath: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)\my_script.ps1
      workingDirectory: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)
```

and my PowerShell script looks like this (heavily edited for brevity):

```
function RestoreNugetModel($SourceDir, $StagingDir, $Lang, $Version)
{
   Set-Location $StagingDir
   $packageConfig = BuildPackageConfig $StagingDir $Lang $Version

   $CMD = "nuget"
   $arg1 = "restore"
   $arg2 = "-Source"
   $arg3 = "${packageConfig}"
   $arg4 = "-PackagesDirectory"
   $arg5 = Join-Path -Path $SourceDir -ChildPath "src/external"
   $arg6 = "-ConfigFile"
   $arg7 = Join-Path -Path $SourceDir -ChildPath "src/modelcheck.test/nuget.config"
   $arg8 = "-Verbosity"
   $arg9 = "detailed"
   $arg10 = "-NonInteractive"
   $output = & $CMD $arg1 $arg2 $arg3 $arg4 $arg5 $arg6 $arg7 $arg8 $arg9 $arg10
   Write-Host $output -join "`n"
   $exitCode = $LASTEXITCODE
   if ($exitCode -eq 0)
   {
       Write-Host "##[command] Restore Complete"
   }
   else
   {
       Write-Host  "##[error] Restore Failed with ${exitCode}"
   }
   return $exitCode
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the nuget command only worked on my local machine because of the nuget cache.

After I cleared the cache, the nuget command failed on my local machine in the same way it did on the ADO build machine, and the root cause was that I had a bad nuget command to begin with; I should not have been specifying the `-Source` flag, and the nuget command should have looked like this:

```
function RestoreNugetModel($SourceDir, $StagingDir, $Lang, $Version)
{
   Set-Location $StagingDir
   $packageConfig = BuildPackageConfig $StagingDir $Lang $Version

   $CMD = "nuget"
   $arg1 = "restore"
   $arg2 = "${packageConfig}"
   $arg3 = "-PackagesDirectory"
   $arg4 = Join-Path -Path $SourceDir -ChildPath "src/external"
   $arg5 = "-ConfigFile"
   $arg6 = Join-Path -Path $SourceDir -ChildPath "src/modelcheck.test/nuget.config"
   $arg7 = "-Verbosity"
   $arg8 = "detailed"
   $arg9 = "-NonInteractive"
   $output = & $CMD $arg1 $arg2 $arg3 $arg4 $arg5 $arg6 $arg7 $arg8 $arg9
   Write-Host $output -join "`n"
   $exitCode = $LASTEXITCODE
   if ($exitCode -eq 0)
   {
       Write-Host "##[command] Restore Complete"
   }
   else
   {
       Write-Host  "##[error] Restore Failed with ${exitCode}"
   }
   return $exitCode
}
```